# Receiving payments in Bitcoin for RESTful API calls

Tags: payment, payment-processors

I'm familiar with different options to receive payments in Bitcoin (Blockchain.info, BitPay, Coinbase, Stripe). But how would one devise a solution to have users pay whenever they call some RESTful API endpoints? First thing that came up my mind is the following:

1. Have user send some initial amount in Bitcoin when they register for API usage on website via solutions mentioned above integrated on website.
2. Then just deduct from their state of Bitcoin for each API call they make.

But is maybe there a solution/standard, where someone wouldn't have to make an account to first transfer Bitcoin and could somehow specify in API call how many Bitcoins to transfer? When I think about it logically, this doesn't seem to be possible as you can't couple together a transfer request with API call, I mean how would you even authorize payment from your personal wallet to the specified address and how much to transfer?

Comment: Note that since this question was asked, [Stripe has discontinued Bitcoin payments](https://fortune.com/2018/07/17/stripe-blockchain/).

Answer (score -1):

There is one: https://github.com/Overtorment/Cashier-BTC/

Disclaimer: coded by me.